# Ansible: append a string to an existing line in a file

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible module to edit the manifest file for kube-apiserver

```
    - --feature-gates=AdvancedAuditing=true
```

I want to append new feature-gate like

```
    - --feature-gates=AdvancedAuditing=true,TTLAfterFinished=true
```

I tried many thing, one of which -

```
- name: append TTLAfterFinished to existing list of feature-gates
  lineinfile:
    path: item.0.item.file_path
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: "^(.*feature-gates.*)$"
    line: '\1,TTLAfterFinished=true'
```

With no luck.. :( Any help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have worked fine for me, but I do not have an `item` varaible.  So I have this:

```
- name: append TTLAfterFinished to existing list of feature-gates
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/file_path"
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: "^(.*feature-gates.*)$"
    line: '\1,TTLAfterFinished=true'
```

Perhaps it is your `item` variable that is the problem.

Comment: Arghhh - `"{{item.0.item.file_path}}"` works! Thanks :)

Comment: Somehow with `line: '\1 -A'` I got the whole line in file replaced with `\1 -A`...

Comment: OK, I forgot about the backrefs, my bad.

Comment: This solution is not idempotent, every time you run it you get another copy added to the line. Use `regexp: "^(match this.*?)( my extra data)?$` This does a non greedy match `.*?`, then checks to see if your string is already at the end, then replaces the line with your extra data only after the first match. So the regex here should be `regexp: "^(.*feature-gates.*?)(,TTLAfterFinished=true)?$`

Answer (score 1):

The below works for me. The entire regular expression should be put inside the the brackets for python to group it.
Using replace module is another option too.

```
 - name: kube-apiserver - append TTLAfterFinished to existing list of feature-gates
   lineinfile:
    path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '(^    - --feature-gates=.*$)'
    line: '\1,TTLAfterFinished=true'
```